# C# file selection and network access?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, networking, file-browser

I'm creating a very simple application that will select files from local drive or from PC connected in a network. 
Application has a `"checkbox"` that can be checked True or False.
Is it right to connect from Network location??
How can I create file browse button with it?

```
private void connect()
{
   try
   {
       if (checkbox1.Checked == false)
       {
          FilePath = @"C:\FILE";
       }
       else
       {
          FilePath = @"\\192.168.0.2\file\"; // That I want Is it work?
       }
       strConn = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + FilePath + @"\;Extensions=csv,txt";
       Connect = new OdbcConnection(strConn);
       Connect.Open();
   }
   catch (Exception Ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? We expect you do to debugging and come here WITH AN ERROR DESCRIPTION, not crying and not even telling us what you think is wrong.

Comment: Yes it's correct but didn't work on Checked event. These are "checkbox1.Checked" and 'ELSE' usage correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to open a file browser on the network ? Did you try `OpenFileDialog` ? It works on network path too, You can use it like this:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = FilePath;
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: He quite explicitly does not want to open a file browser on the network. Amazing answer. Read the question.

Comment: @TomTom I don't really understood his question but i tried to help him ! Stop critic and help ! What does `How can I create file browse button` mean for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's very helpful then Exactly I just wanted file selection with two way - 1st local machine, 2nd network shared folder

Comment: Did it solved your problem? Can you put the answer as resolved?